# Flutter - Wrap text on overflow, like insert ellipsis or fade

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, user-interface

I'm trying to create a line in which center text has a maximum size, and if the text content is too large, it fits in size.

I insert the `TextOverflow.ellipsis` property to shorten the text and inserting the triple points `...` but it is not working.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF26C6DA),
    ),
    body: new ListView  (
      children: <Widget>[
        new Card(
          child: new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 18.0),
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 24.0),
                  child: new CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                    radius: 16.0,
                  )
                ),
                new Container(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 13.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    'Text lar...',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 13.0,
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      color: new Color(0xFF212121),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  child: new Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Text(
                            'Bill  ',
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12.0,
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              color: new Color(0xFF9E9E9E)
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Text(
                            '\$ -999.999.999,95',
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              color: new Color(0xFF212121)
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      new Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Text(
                            'Limit  ',
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12.0,
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              color: new Color(0xFF9E9E9E)
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Text(
                            'R\$ 900.000.000,95',
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              color: new Color(0xFF9E9E9E)
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ]
                  )
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ),
      ]
    )
  );
}
```

**result:**

[image]

**expected:**

[image]

Comment: The title and content of this question don't match. Your *expected* result shows ellipsizing. However, the title states `wrap` and `fade`. Please adjust you title so it matches your actual question. It confuses this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930754/flutter-wrapping-text

Answer (score 761, accepted):

You should wrap your `Container` in a [`Flexible`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) to let your `Row` know that it's ok for the `Container` to be narrower than its intrinsic width. [`Expanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) will also work.

[image: screenshot]

```
Flexible(
  child: new Container(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 13.0),
    child: new Text(
      'Text largeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee',
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      style: new TextStyle(
        fontSize: 13.0,
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        color: new Color(0xFF212121),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: I have a similar problem on Column. This approach isn't working for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206221/flutter-text-inside-an-expanded-widget-within-a-column-overflowing

Comment: are there any way we could implement this in textfield?

Comment: if you want it to also have the text wrap_content specify the fit property with FlexFit.loose,

Comment: This approach does not always work. In my case, all the TextFlow props like elipsis or fade or clip do not work for a text inside an InkWell and insided a row and another row. All permuttations on row, container, text, inkwell, column etc with expanded and flexible FAIL.

Comment: If this approach does not work for you when you use Column, wrap the Column in Flexible

Comment: Thanks a lot @IsaacOluwatemilorun It worked like charm. `Flexible -> Column -> Text()`.

Comment: For column and text overflow combination, here is a clue to solve.  Row->Expanded->Your Column.  here is more details in the answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65656774/flutter-text-overflow-on-column-widget

Comment: I try to use `Expanded` and it does not work, but when I try to use `Flexible` to wrap my Column, now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 316):

***Using Ellipsis***

```
Text(
  "This is a long text",
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
),
```

[image]

---

***Using Fade***

```
Text(
  "This is a long text",
  overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
  maxLines: 1,
  softWrap: false,
),
```

[image]

---

***Using Clip***

```
Text(
  "This is a long text",
  overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
  maxLines: 1,
  softWrap: false,
),
```

[image]

---

**Note:**

If you are using `Text` inside a `Row`, you can put above `Text` inside `Expanded` like:

```
Expanded(
  child: AboveText(),
)
```

Comment: can i add when text overflow then add a flat button like ...more link

Comment: This doesn't work if you have text and another widget (e.g. icon) centred inside a row.

Comment: `softWrap: false` is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Hey, what if we want to add, for example, a new page with the text that is overflowing?

Comment: `softWrap: false` essentially says apply the effect horizontally instead of vertically. I didn't notice with the ellipses, but when switching to fade I needed it so it didn't fade the bottom of the text or just wrap anyway

Comment: @kilkfoe That's why you need to provide `maxLines` as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Hay @CopsOnRoad  I have customeTile brother TextOverflow.ellipsis is not working even i used softWrap: false and also limit maxLine to 1 still my text overflow from side.

Comment: @user11908262 I can't help you without seeing the code.

Answer (score 59):

First, wrap your `Row` or `Column` in `Expanded` widget

Then

```
Text(
    'your long text here',
    overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
    maxLines: 1,
    softWrap: false,
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
)
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right way, first wrapping the Column inside the Expanded really worked! and to use the Text inside the Column children.

Answer (score 39):

**1. clip**

Clip the overflowing text to fit its container.

```
SizedBox(
          width: 120.0,
          child: Text(
            "Enter Long Text",
            maxLines: 1,
            overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
            softWrap: false,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
        ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

**2.fade**

Fade the overflowing text to transparent.

```
SizedBox(
          width: 120.0,
          child: Text(
            "Enter Long Text",
            maxLines: 1,
            overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            softWrap: false,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
        ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

**3.ellipsis**

Use an ellipsis to indicate that the text has overflowed.

```
SizedBox(
          width: 120.0,
          child: Text(
            "Enter Long Text",
            maxLines: 1,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            softWrap: false,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
        ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

**4.visible**

Render overflowing text outside of its container.

```
SizedBox(
          width: 120.0,
          child: Text(
            "Enter Long Text",
            maxLines: 1,
            overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
            softWrap: false,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
        ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 35):

You can use this code snipped to show text with ellipsis

```
Text(
    "Introduction to Very very very long text",
    maxLines: 1,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    softWrap: false,
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
),
```

Comment: Also please include a description of this code to explain how it answers the question.

Answer (score 25):

You can do that by First wrapping your **`Column`** inside **`Flexible`** or **`Expanded`** and then use **`Text`** as usual and it will get wrapped up automatically.

```dart
Container(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Flexible(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text("This text is so long and long and long and long and long and that's why it is not wrapping to next line.")
          ]
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image: Wrapped Text Screenshot]

Comment: Are you sure this is the output?

Comment: @FranciscaMkina Ya its the output for the `text` you are seeing below the image when I have tested on my device.

Comment: What I see is for you to maintain the dimensions of that single item, you need to keep your text limited to a certain length. If you put the very long text, that one item is going to be long like a snake.

Answer (score 22):

You can do it like that

```
Expanded(
   child: Text(
   'Text',
   overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
   maxLines: 1
   )
)
```

Answer (score 16):

**Text inside Row**.

**1. Preference of text in  Column 1 > Column 2**

[image]

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: const [
    Text(
      "This is very very  long text in column 1 of Row",
      style: TextStyle(
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, backgroundColor: Colors.green),
    ),
    Flexible(
      child: Text("This is very very  long text in column 2 of Row",
          style: TextStyle(
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              backgroundColor: Colors.yellow)),
    )
  ],
)
```

**2. Preference of text in  Column 2 > Column 1**

[image]

```
   Row(
     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
     children: const [
        Flexible(
          child: Text(
             "This is very very  long text in column 1 of Row",
             style: TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,  backgroundColor: Colors.green),
          ),
        ),
       Text("This is very very  long text in column 2 of Row",
        style: TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, backgroundColor: Colors.yellow))
    ],
   )
```

**3. Same Preference**
[image]

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: const [
    Flexible(
      child: Text(
        "This is very very  long text in column 1 of Row",
        style: TextStyle(
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, backgroundColor: Colors.green),
      ),
    ),
    Flexible(
      child: Text("This is very very  long text in column 2 of Row",
          style: TextStyle(
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              backgroundColor: Colors.yellow)),
    )
  ],
)
```

**Text inside Column**

define the `maxLine` attribute.

[image]

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: const [
    Text(
      "This is very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very  long text in Row 1 of Column",
      maxLines: 2,
      style: TextStyle(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
    ),
    Text("This is very very  long text in Row 2 of Column",
        style: TextStyle(
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow))
  ],
)
```

###### Note: If your requirement is to show the entrie content without overflow but not messing with the constraints, remove the `overflow` attribute but keep the `Flexible` as is:

[image]

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: const [
    Flexible(
      child: Text(
        "This is very very  long text in column 1 of Row",
        style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.green),
      ),
    ),
    Flexible(
      child: Text("This is very very  long text in column 2 of Row",
          style: TextStyle(
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              backgroundColor: Colors.yellow)),
    )
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 15):

One way to fix an overflow of a Text Widget within a row if for example a chat message can be one really long line. You can create a Container and a BoxConstraint with a maxWidth in it.

```
            Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 200),
                child: Text(
                  (chatName == null) ? " ": chatName,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      fontSize: 17.0),
                )
            ),
```

Answer (score 14):

```dart
SizedBox(
    width: 200.0,
    child: Text('PRODUCERS CAVITY FIGHTER 50X140g',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2))
```

Just wrap in inside a widget that can take a specific width for it to work or it will assume the width of the parent container.

Answer (score 11):

I went through such a problem several times using rows within columns. Here's a good way to fix it:

```
 return Column(
  children: [
    Row(
      children: const [
        Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.red), // an example icon            
        // use the flexible widget above the padding
        Flexible(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
            child: Text(
              "Exemple of text",
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // I used ellipsis, but it works with others (fade, clip, etc.)
              maxLines: 1,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
  ],
);
```

Notice that I put the **Flexible** above the padding, because when the text grew, the padding also broke the screen. It would be useless to put it only in **Text**. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Wrapping whose child elements are in a row or column, please wrap your column or row is new Flexible();

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4128

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your situation, I think this is the best approach below.

```
final maxWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4;
Container(
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        child: Text('This is long text',
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: maxWidth),
),
```

Answer (score 6):

If you simply place text as a child(ren) of a column, this is the easiest way to have text automatically wrap. Assuming you don't have anything more complicated going on.  In those cases, I would think you would create your container sized as you see fit and put another column inside and then your text.  This seems to work nicely.  Containers want to shrink to the size of its contents, and this seems to naturally conflict with wrapping, which requires more effort.

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('This long text will wrap very nicely if there isn\'t room beyond the column\'s total width and if you have enough vertical space available to wrap into.',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: primaryColor),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Also wrapping the Text with Flexible and wrapping Flexible with a Column or Row seems to work.

Answer (score 6):

Use an ellipsis to indicate that the text has overflowed.

```
SizedBox(
              width: 120.0,
              child: Text(
                "Enter Long Text",
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                softWrap: false,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    SizedBox(
                        width: width-100,
                        child: Text(
                          "YOUR LONG TEXT HERE...",
                          maxLines: 3,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                          softWrap: true,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are facing the problem inside a Row a widget, try to wrap the Text widget with Expanded

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Text('first'),
    Expanded(
      child: Text('a really long message...'),
    )
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the Container with Expanded()

```
Expanded (child: Container(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 24.0),
                  child: new CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                    radius: 16.0,
                  )
                ),
                new Container(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 13.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    'Text lar...',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 13.0,
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      color: new Color(0xFF212121),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
),
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 3):

[image]
In Column We make text ellipsis by wraping column with flexibale widget,

```
 Container(
            height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 20,
            width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 88,
            child: Flexible(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  PicClipper(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                      circularRadius: 30,
                      circularImage: imageUrl[index]),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 3,
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    text:
                        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipiscing elit.',
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                    textColor: AppColors.blackTextColor,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    fontFamily: "Poppins",
                    maxLine: 3,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Named parameter `textOverflow` should be `overflow`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the parent Container needs to be given a maxWidth of the proper size.  It looks like the Text box will fill whatever space it is given above.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
In Row We make text ellipsis to go second line by wraping  firstly Text with Container and than wrap container with flexible widget

```
 Container(

            height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 10,
            width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 88,

            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment:
              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                PicClipper(height: 50, width:50, circularRadius: 30, circularImage:imageUrl[index]),
                SizedBox(
                  width:
                  SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 3,
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    child: const
                    AppText
                      (
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      text:
                      'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipiscing elit.',
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                      textColor: AppColors.blackTextColor,
                      textOverflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      fontFamily: "Poppins",
                      maxLine: 3,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple class TextOneLine from package assorted_layout_widgets.

Just put your text in that class.

For example:

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      SvgPicture.asset(
        loadAsset(SVG_CALL_GREEN),
        width: 23,
        height: 23,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
      SizedBox(width: 16),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            TextOneLine(
              widget.firstText,
              style: findTextStyle(widget.firstTextStyle),
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 4),
            TextOneLine(
              widget.secondText,
              style: findTextStyle(widget.secondTextStyle),
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Icon(
        Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
        color: Styles.iOSArrowRight,
      )
    ],
  )
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: What to import here. 'package:assorted_layout_widgets/assorted_layout_widgets.dart'; doesn't work

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
 Expanded(
  child: Container(
      child: Text('OVER FLOW TEST TEXTTTT',
          overflow: TextOverflow.fade)),
),
```

This will show `OVER FLOW`. If there is an overflow, it  will be handled.

Answer (score -3):

TO ADJUST YOUR CONTAINER SIZE DYNAMICALLY BASED ON THE LENGTH OF THE TEXT.
USE THIS:

```
Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "O(E2)hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh1233455676788",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 24,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```