# For long texts in TextField widget, how to show text from the starting after unfocus?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image: Email TextField]

The above image is the TextField. My email address is "dinesh12345678901@gmail.com". After unfocused, I need to display the email from starting like below image. Is there anyway to achieve this easily in flutter?

For example : Refer gmail app.

[image]

Comment: No not easily. But you could probably build off of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580658/flutter-textfield-how-to-shrink-the-font-if-the-text-entered-overflows

Comment: is there any other way without reducing the font size?

Comment: You are going to have to custom code yourself a TexField to do this. The link is just an idea of how to get started doing that.

Comment: Thanks Kent. I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `selection` on your `TextEditingController` when you're unfocusing your `TextField`. Here is an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 48),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(height: 16),
              TextField(
                controller: _textEditingController,
                focusNode: _focusNode,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 36),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  _textEditingController.selection =
                      TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: 0));
                  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
                  _focusNode.unfocus();
                },
                color: Colors.red,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text('Unfocus'),
              ),
            ],
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]