# Fade animation in selected tab text in flutter. The selected tab text occupies space even when its opacity is zero

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have four tabs in flutter application. Each tab has is a child of AnimatedContainer Each tab has icon and text but the text is only visible for selected tab.(The width of container increases and text appears). I applied fade animation to text so that text fades in when selected. But the text overflow is seen until the enough width is available for the text to appear.

How can this be achieved so that text does not overflow?

Problem is illustrated in the link below.

[image: Illustration of the problem.]

*Thanks!!*

Comment: Have you tried to use the `overflow` property of [Text](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your `Text` in `Flexible` widget and add `softWrap:false` property to your `Text`:

```
new Flexible(
    child: Text(
      "Very, very, very, long text...",
      softWrap: false,
    )
)
```

Also maybe for you will be useful information about `Text` property `overflow`:
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/TextOverflow-class.html

This link show you how to use `overflow` property:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54222581/2978855

Good Luck!