# Show paragraph with ellipsis in Flutter Web is broken?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Hello and thanks for any help, I'm trying to put an ellipsis at the end of a paragraph, it seems so easy to do in Flutter... but, in my case, it doesnt work with ellipsis.

It works as expected with TextOverflow.clip & TextOverflow.fade, I tried everything (put inside fixed container, flexible container...), and every, supossedly, working code I found seem to not work in my case, maybe a bug of 1.9? I have something like this:

```
Text(
  'Tree lines text for demostration puropuse,tree lines text for demonstration purpose, lines text for demostration puropuse',
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  maxLines: 3,
),
```

It works great with Text Overflow.clip & Text Overflow.fade but, with exactly the same environment, it doesn't work with Text Overflow.ellipsis.

Comment: What is the width of your parent container? i.e. on a full width galaxy S8 there is not enough text to show the ellipsis. By adding more text I can confirm the ellipsis is showing on the third line as expected.

Comment: Hello Yann!, I reallized now I didnt mention I'm working in a Flutter Web project, maybe thats the problem here, will put the tag and explain in the main post (sorry), as I mentioned I did tried to put in sized container, what works with the other options (Clip and Fade dosent with Ellipsis.)

Comment: Ah OK so I can't help here. Maybe take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579918/flutter-insert-overflow-ellipsis-in-text) but if it works with other options it may be a bug (also see [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33223). Cross browsers multiline ellipsis is impossible to do in pure CSS so maybe Flutter web have the same issue :/

Comment: Thank you!, didn't seen [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33223) before, that would be the case :-)

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you do not have required character to show elipsis. In another word, as name suggest your text is not overflowed to show elipsis. So, try by reducing `maxLines: 3,` to `1`.

If you have specific character limit, you can check for the text length and add few dots by substring the text(And of course this is not preferable solution).

Comment: Hi and thanks Blasanka for you time ;-)... Well what you say is what would be the expected in the css world, but in flutter I was expecting a more intelligent behaviour,I dont want 1 line as I explained, what i would expect was a paragraph with three lines and at the end of the last line the three dots.