# How to prevent Overflow Horizontally?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am struggling to make this work but I tried everything and still, I can't make this work. So, I have the structure below:

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      CircleAvatar(
        radius: 40.0,
        backgroundImage: Image
            .network(
          '$thumbnail',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        )
            .image,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 20,
      ),
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Really biiiig drink name here',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 28
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'Category goes here',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.8)
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

And it renders like this:

[overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ30b.png)

How can I clip, or wrap that title text without defining a fixed width to a parent widget?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54222581/5882307

Comment: wrap your `Column` inside a `Expanded` widget

Comment: Combining @OMiShah answer with ChyperX, I achieved what I wanted. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Expanded` widgets to resist overflow of view

[image]

```
Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 40.0,
                    backgroundImage: Image.network('https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ30b.png', fit: BoxFit.cover,).image,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                  Expanded(child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Really biiiig drink name here',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.yellow,
                            fontSize: 28
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Category goes here',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.red.withOpacity(.8)
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ), ),

                ],
              ),
```

Comment: Accepting this one, every answer says the same thing. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Expanded` to your inner Column to give it a defined width.

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    CircleAvatar(
      radius: 40.0,
      backgroundImage: Image.network(
        '$thumbnail',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ).image,
    ),
    SizedBox(
      width: 20,
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Really biiiig drink name here',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 28
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'Category goes here',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.8)
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add an Expand to where the overflow is taking place it should solve the problem.