# Text Overflow in Flutter code not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to ellipsis the text in Flutter app but I am not able to set it.

I design the view as below

```
Positioned(
            bottom: 20,
            left: 10,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  snapshot.data.results[index].title,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  snapshot.data.results[index].release_date,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      letterSpacing: 1.2),
                ),
              ],
            ))
```

[image: Screen Shot Ellipsis]

Comment: I have the same widget, but the accepted answer doesn't work. How did you do it ?

Comment: Use Expanded Widgets if flexible is not working and set text overflow. If you want to every letter go with multiline. I would suggest

Comment: I ended up using Column with mainAxisAlignment.end instead of Positioned. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should wrap your text with `Flexible` or `Expanded` widgets like below:

```
    Flexible(child:Text("Text goes here"),
```

for more info try out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579918/flutter-wrap-text-on-overflow-like-insert-ellipsis-or-fade) link

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem at hand. It just shrinks the text and that's not what's needed. The text should be the same size and truncate the text in the manner chosen in TextOverflow.

If someone asks how to get overflow to work, the answer isn't to ignore the idea of overflow and just shrink the text to make it fit.

Answer (score 4):

I recently encountered something similar. If you inspect the constraints on the renderObject of your `Text` Widget using the DartDevTools, you are quite probably going to find the `maxWidth` constraint to be infinity. Therefore the `Text` Widget is not aware it is supposed to be wrapping (default behaviour) or appling ellipsis (in your case) to the text you provide.

The solution in my case was to wrap the `Text` Widget in an `Expanded`.

Comment: you could try to wrap the Text in a container with a fixed small width, to test whether ellipsis works in principle if the Text widget knows its maxWidth. This is no permanent solution however.

Answer (score 1):

You shuld wrap your widget with Expanded

```
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      ("Mortal Kombat"),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      ("12/10/2022"),
                      style:
                          TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4)),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      ("Express yourself with a custom text design created just fo`r you by a professional designer. Need ideas? We’ve collected some amazing examples of text images from our global community of designers. Get inspired and start planning the perfect text design today."),
                      // style: TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),

                      maxLines: 2,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.