# Text inside ListvVew gets wrapped instead of overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This widget create individual elements of listview

```
Widget _playListItems(int _index) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(

                //This text gets wrapped instead of fading

                _playList[_index]["title"],
                overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 22,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Colors.white70),
              ),
              //Other Text
            ],
          ), flex: 6),
          Expanded(child: //button inside inkwell
          , flex: 1)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The text is wrapped in expanded. I also tried replacing Expanded with Flexible but to no avail. The text still gets wrapped around.

Comment: Probably this could answer your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54222581/2281066

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I was missing `maxLines: 1` in my `Text()` widget. Thanks to `xion` for pointing out that question in the comments.