# TextFormField in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a problem. I create a TextFormField. When text length is so lengthy, I want textField will display as the below image. Help me. Thank you.

[image]

This is code:

```
TextFormField(
            controller: nameController,
            enabled: false,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            style: TextUtil.regularArial.copyWith(
              fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(14),
              color: ColorUtil.grey8E8E8E,
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              filled: true,
              isDense: true,
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1),
              ),
              hintText: "Email",
              hintStyle: TextUtil.regularArial.copyWith(
                fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(14),
                color: ColorUtil.grey7A7A7A,
              ),
            ),
            validator: (value){
             
            },
          ),
```

Comment: what you have tried so far? please share the code

Comment: you can achieve this in a text with overflow: ellipsis property. You could also try @youOne's answer below. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579918/flutter-wrap-text-on-overflow-like-insert-ellipsis-or-fade

Comment: I updated my code on post.

Answer (score 1):

Try add maxLines: null

```
TextFormField(maxLines: null)
```

If the maxLines property is null, there is no limit to the number of lines, and the wrap is enabled.

Comment: I used maxLines: null but it only expand height TextField

Comment: I want to display TextFormField on only one line

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know the answer, and why would you do that anyway someone input their email address and they can't see the rest of the email. But if you trying to do it with Text you can try adding TextOverflow.ellipsis `Text("Very Long Text", overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)` it will work like charm

Comment: No matter, Thank for your helping.