# How to remove over flow error from a container with fixed width and height

Tags: flutter

I have a container with a fixed with and height, but when I added widgets into it, the container overflows. How do I curb this:

this is my code snippet:

```
    class InfoCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 150,
      height: 300,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 43, 135, 65)),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),

      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network("", width: 150, height: 150,),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        width: 80,
                        child: Text(
                            "Prayer for the Nation",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 15
                          ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    Image.asset("assets/images/tag.png", width: 15, height: 20,),
                  ],
                ),
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text("Intercede", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),)
                ),
                Text(
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor...",
                  textAlign:TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12
                  ),),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is what I get
[image]

how do I make the Text not overflow, but get clipped.

Comment: Do you want the content to fit into the Container (warp the content with a FittedBox?) or do you want the container to expand?

Comment: @kazume I want the remaining text to cut off

Comment: Check this answer and see if it helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44580054/5199833