# Flutter text overflow on column widget

Tags: flutter

I am using row widget in which i am showing text in a column. But issue is its overflow the width of text.

My code

```
    Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'images/preinform-battery-screen-icon@2x.png',
              height: height * 0.045,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                    'KMC-216, TOHEED COLONY, SECTOR 11, BLOCK L, ST6, KARACHI, ABC, XYZ, DMG',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                    ),
                  )),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: height * 0.007,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Home Adress',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 17,
                        fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                        color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

I want to show text on left and not overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can wrap all the childrens of your `Row` in `Flexible` or `Expanded` widgets.
Here's a preview:

[image]

You can access the preview and code [here](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/8c9ce88db846b094eee74b41431cf7ec?)