# Flutter Text overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-text

How to control TextOverFlow if don't know the const width of the box.
I know about

```
Text(
      'some Text',
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
)
```

but is there any way to wrap widgets like expanded or flexible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579918/flutter-wrap-text-on-overflow-like-insert-ellipsis-or-fade

Comment: I think you have state the solution itself, which is using `Flexible` with `overflow` attributes to control the text overflow. It's better if you can clarify the problem that prevented you from using these widgets, what went wrong or if any error came up.

Comment: @Bach that's right, but it not work with Flexible, for that, I need to wrap it in a container and again give it width.

Comment: @AliAzimoshan Thanks for clarify Ali. Can you give us more code of your current implementation of `Flexible`, maybe the screen that contains it? It's easier to pinpoint the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
FittedBox(
      fit: setToWidth ? BoxFit.contain : BoxFit.none,
      child: Text(
        displayText,
        maxLines: 2,
        textAlign: textAlign,
        style: setToWidth
            ? TextStyle(
                fontWeight: fontWeight,
                color: textColor,
                fontFamily: AppFonts.circularStd,
              )
            : TextStyle(
                fontWeight: fontWeight,
                color: textColor,
                fontFamily: AppFonts.circularStd,
                fontSize: textSize),
      ),
    );
```

Try with this

Answer (score 0):

You can try AutoSizeText instead.
https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text

Note: it'll increase your overall app size as it requires external dependencies. But it'll give you some extra features such as maxLines and minLines. I will suggest read more about it.