# how to trim text in textformfield if very long text like overflow.ellipse in Text?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

how to trim text in textformfield if very long text like overflow.ellipse in Text?

[image: TextFormField]

Comment: do you want to trim text till end or you want ellipse feature like android native??

Comment: you can give maxLines for textformfield.

Comment: just trim to show in TextField but actual text not trim ... because if line > 1 will be overflow .. so i want trim ellipse to fix overflow @DeePanShu

Comment: i've try maxLine = 1 .. but, is not trim ... i can scroll horizontall in TextField to see long text @JigneshPatel

Comment: @Afdal Can you give maxLine = 2?

Comment: did you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737859/10954249

Comment: this Text Widget sir.. not TextFormField @DeePanShu

Comment: i've try.. is not trim.. but, i see height of TextField 2 and i can scroll vertical

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62963 : no solution set for this, you have to make your custom TextInputField

Comment: ohh i see,,, thanks @DeePanShu

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question and the comments, it looks like the problem you have might be related to layouts, rather than the `Text` widget itself.

You need to make sure your `Text` widget has a bounded width, for example, you can use `Expanded` to make it fill all remaining spaces in `Row`:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded( // won't work if you remove the `Expanded` here
      child: Text(
        'lorem ipsum ' * 20,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
    ),
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('Button'),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comparison with and without the `Expanded` widget in the above code:

[image: demo picture]

Similarly, you can use `SizedBox` or any other methods, to make sure the `Text` widget has a finite width.