# Flutter ignoring overflow and wrap settings

Tags: flutter, text, overflow

I am trying to work out why Flutter is ignoring my overflow and wrap settings on my Text widget

[image]

```
Card(
            borderOnForeground: true,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
              side: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.grey[200],
                width: 1.0,
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage:
                                    widget.user.profileImageUrl.isEmpty
                                        ? const AssetImage(
                                            'assets/images/avatar-5.png')
                                        : CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                            widget.user.profileImageUrl,
                                          )),
                            const SizedBox(width: 10),
                            Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                      '${widget.user.firstName} ${widget.user.lastName[0]}'),
                                  Text(task.desc,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                                      maxLines: 2,
                                      softWrap: false,
                                      style: Theme.of(context)
                                          .textTheme
                                          .bodyText1),
                                ]),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(children: [
                          const Icon(Icons.calendar_today_outlined, size: 12),
                          const SizedBox(width: 6),
                          Text(DateFormat('E, d MMM').format(task.due),
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption)
                        ]),
                      ]),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      _buildBudget(formatCurrency.format(widget.task.budget))
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Row(children: [
                        const Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined, size: 12),
                        const SizedBox(width: 6),
                        Text(task.location,
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption)
                      ]),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a similar question, that might help you:

[Flutter - Wrap text on overflow, like insert ellipsis or fade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579918/flutter-wrap-text-on-overflow-like-insert-ellipsis-or-fade)

---

To achieve the desired effect, you have to tell your text widgets how much space they should take. For example by wrapping your column (the parent of the overflowing text widgets) with a `Flexible` or `Expanded`.

I tried to minify your example a little bit to make it more obvious:

```
class CardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // Your other widegts
            // Row(children: [ ... ]),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                // Your circle avatar with a constant size
                Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.red),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                // The important part
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      const Text('Firstname Lastname'),
                      const Text(
                          'Really long description that does not fit on to the screen',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                          maxLines: 2),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            // Your other widegts
            // Row(children: [ ... ]),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note that you should remove the `softWrap: false`. If false, the glyphs in the text will be positioned as if there was unlimited horizontal space.

If the text exceeds 2 lines, the faded overflow effect will be visible. If you do not want that, just remove the `maxLines` attribute.

---

**Full Example**

Here is a full example with a structure, that will work within a `ListView` assuming location, date and budget widgets should be on the same line:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: [
        CardWidget(),
        CardWidget(),
        CardWidget(),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class CardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      borderOnForeground: true,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
        side: BorderSide(
          width: 1.0,
        ),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(height: 50, width: 50, color: Colors.red),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text('Firstname Lastname'),
                      Text(
                          "Long text that exceeds multiple lines. Long text that exceeds multiple lines. Long text that exceeds multiple lines",
                          overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                          maxLines: 3,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 25),
            Row(
              children: [
                // Location and Date
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined, size: 12),
                    const SizedBox(width: 6),
                    Text("Location"),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 25),
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const Icon(Icons.calendar_today_outlined, size: 12),
                    const SizedBox(width: 6),
                    Text("Date"),
                  ],
                ),
                // The budget widget
                Expanded(child: Container()),
                Text("200"),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: as above we have tried this this wrapping column with expanded but It actually causes more issues

Comment: doing as above causes a render box error as you cannot have an expanded within list view with shrink-wrap

Comment: Ah, you are using a list view around the widget you just showed in you example? I just tried it within a ListView and I did not get a renderBox error. But I noticed, you use many stacked rows, e.g.: Row(children: [Row( ...)]). I recommend reducing them. I will update my answer, just give me a second.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Column` in a `Expanded`.. should be work

```
Expanded(child:Column(...))
```

and try to add `Expanded` (wrap `Row`) here too (last line in code):

```
Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(child:Row(  ////HERE
```

The `Row` does not have a specified width. So one of the childs should have an `Expanded`

ok i have tested... here the full code:

```
Card(
        borderOnForeground: true,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
          side: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.grey,
            width: 1.0,
          ),
        ),
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
            child: Column(children: [
              Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: const AssetImage('assets/images/avatar-5.png')),
                          const SizedBox(width: 10),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
                              Text('${'widget.user.firstName'} '),
                              Text('task.desc',
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                                  maxLines: 2,
                                  softWrap: false,
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1),
                            ]),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(children: [
                      const Icon(Icons.calendar_today_outlined, size: 12),
                      const SizedBox(width: 6),
                      Text('DateFormat( ).format(task.due)', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption)
                    ]),
                  ]),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [Text('dff')],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Row(children: [
                    const Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined, size: 12),
                    const SizedBox(width: 6),
                    Text('task.location', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption)
                  ])
                ],
              )
            ])));
```

Comment: tried this it does not. gives errors around render box

Comment: a i see... i update my answer

Comment: not sure I am following what you are saying here

Comment: 2 expanded are required... look in my full code example where

Answer (score 0):

Wrap  child of Column with Flexible :

```
Column(
    mainAxisSize : MainAxisSize.min,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
         Flexible (child :Text(
              '${widget.user.firstName} ${widget.user.lastName[0]}')),
         Flexible (
               child :Text(task.desc,
               overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
               maxLines: 2,
               softWrap: false,
               style: Theme.of(context)
                   .textTheme
                   .bodyText1)),
               ]),
```