# Icons get together in flutter bottom navigation bar with floating button

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

I'm making a bottom navigation bar using Inkwell, but as much as I tried solutions, I couldn't separate each icon in its respective space, I don't know what is failing me.

I tried with materialbuttom but the result was almost the same, although if there is any other alternative or suggestion I would like to know! Thankyou

[image]

I added the code

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    notchMargin: 10,
    child: SizedBox(
      height: 60,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Material(
                child: Center(
                  child: InkWell(
                    focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                    hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentTab = 0;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.home),
                        Text("Home"),
                        //const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Material(
                child: Center(
                  child: InkWell(
                    focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                    hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentTab = 1;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.group),
                        Text("Grupos"),
                        //const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Material(
                child: Center(
                  child: InkWell(
                      focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                      hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          currentTab = 2;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.checklist_outlined),
                          Text("Completadas"),
                          //const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10))
                        ],
                      )),
                ),
              ),
              Material(
                child: Center(
                  child: InkWell(
                    focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                    hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentTab = 3;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.person),
                        Text("Perfil")
                        //const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can think `bottomNavigationBar`  contains 5 widgets, one of the widget is `FloatingActionButton`. Therefor, we will include another widget as middle item of row's children that will cover `FloatingActionButton` space.

While items may have different sizes, we also need to align properly. We can wrap every widget with `Expanded`. ALso you can test with `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,` or using `LayoutBuilder`s constraints width on each item. If you find text overflow, you can wrap `Flexible(child: Text()`. More about [text on overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44579918/10157127)

```dart
 Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Expanded(child: Material(...)),
    Expanded(child: Material(...)),
    Expanded(child: const SizedBox()), // this will handle the fab spacing
    Expanded(child: Material(...)),
    Expanded(child: Material(...)),

   ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! the explanation helped me a lot, besides that I didn't know how to apply the expanded, it was perfect! I will read about the link you added

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    notchMargin: 10,
    child: SizedBox(
      height: 60,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Material(
            child: Center(
              child: InkWell(
                focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    currentTab = 0;
                  });
                },
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.home),
                    Text("Home"),
                    //const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Material(
            child: Center(
              child: InkWell(
                focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    currentTab = 1;
                  });
                },
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.group),
                    Text("Grupos"),
                    //const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(),//to make space for the floating button
          Material(
            child: Center(
              child: InkWell(
                  focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                  hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                  highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      currentTab = 2;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.checklist_outlined),
                      Text("Completadas"),
                      //const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10))
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
          ),
          Material(
            child: Center(
              child: InkWell(
                focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    currentTab = 3;
                  });
                },
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.person),
                    Text("Perfil")
                    //const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Result looks like this

[image: Result looks like this]

Answer (score 2):

Try below code hope its help to you, I have try another way.

You can refer [here](https://fluttergems.dev/bottom-navigation-bar/) some packages for

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Text(
      'Hello, World!',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    notchMargin: 5,
    child: Row(
      //children inside bottom appbar
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.home,
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.group,
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.checklist,
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.person,
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Your Result Screen-> [image]