# Material 3 BottomAppBar Support Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, themes, material3, bottomappbar

I am using `material3: true` in `ThemeData`

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Bottom App Bar')),
        floatingActionButtonLocation:
        FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: const Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {},),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          notchMargin: 8.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {},),
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {},),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
```

I have this code, and I don't see the notch margin and the curve in the BottomAppBar

[image]

Doctor

```
Flutter 3.7.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b06b8b2710 (3 months ago) • 2023-01-23 16:55:55 -0800
Engine • revision b24591ed32
Tools • Dart 2.19.0 • DevTools 2.20.1
```

But the expected design is something like this
[image]

Is there any way to migrate to material3 ?

Comment: Which notch you are talking about? System buttons?

Comment: For that you will need to use the CustomPaint class and draw whatever you want accordingly.

Comment: if I set `material3:false` it works. but how do I migrate to `material3` ?

Comment: @Balaji please refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71346768/13997210) hope its help to you.

Comment: sorry same result @RavindraS.Patil

Comment: @Balaji I have test your code its working well like your expected image

Comment: can you set `material3` to `true` in `ThemeData` ?

Answer (score -1):

Wrap that widget with Theme with useMaterial3:false

```
 bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
    data: ThemeData(useMaterial3: false),
    child: BottomAppBar(
      shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          IconButton(
            tooltip: 'Open navigation menu',
            icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          const Spacer(),
          IconButton(
            tooltip: 'Search',
            icon: const Icon(Icons.chat_bubble),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          const Spacer(
            flex: 3,
          ),
          IconButton(
            tooltip: 'Favorite',
            icon: const Icon(Icons.assignment_ind),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          const Spacer(),
          IconButton(
            tooltip: 'Favorite',
            icon: const Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).