# Flutter - How to align header Listview's elements to his children?

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout

[image]

I would like to align my children with the header's elements. If the first element of the header could start closer to the edge, it will be nice.

Also, as you can see there is only 5 elements for the header, so I have put a SizedBox to have the space but do you have a better solution ?

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget _listItem(index) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,children: [
        Text("Test"),
        Text('Test'),
        Text('Test'),
        Text('Test'),
        Text('Test'),
        Icon(
          Icons.create_outlined,
          color: Colors.grey,
          size: 36.0,
        ),
      ],)
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List L = [1,2,3,4];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
      ),
      body:
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
              child:
                Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        height: 50,
                        child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,children: const [
                          Text('Test',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                          Text('Test',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                          Text('Test',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                          Text('Test',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                          Text('Test',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                          SizedBox(width: 30),
                        ],),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child:
                          ListView.separated(
                              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return const Divider(thickness: 1, color: Colors.blue);
                              },
                              itemCount: L.length,
                              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                                return _listItem(index);
                              }),
                      ),
                    ],
                )
          )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the row's children with `Expanded` widget, therefor everyone will get the same width.

```dart
Widget _listItem(index) {
    return Container(
        // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Row(
      children: const [
        Text("Test"),
        Text('Test'),
        Text('Test'),
        Text('Test'),
        Text('Test'),
        Icon(
          Icons.create_outlined,
          color: Colors.grey,
          size: 36.0,
        ),
      ].map((e) => Expanded(child: e)).toList(),
    ));
  }
```

The same goes for others one.

Comment: For better UI I will suggest using `LayoutBuilder` on scaffold body and use it's constraints to provide width on children.

Comment: Not clear... Is it for responsive ?

Comment: yap , [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) is more that.

Comment: Your first code works but the problem is: I've replaced header's elements with long two-words (eg: "manager name") and it's writing the text on 2 lines.

Comment: if you like to clip the text you can use `overflow` and `maxLines` property. More one [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44579918/10157127)