# Flutter - Wrap text with overflow.elipsis, it won't work like the way i want

Tags: flutter, dart, text, flutter-layout, flutter-text

this is my code for the text section for that elipsis

```dart
         Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 13.0),
                      child: const Text(
                        '\$ 900.000.000',
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Flexible(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

i'm trying to create an line that will show price that look like below this.

> $ 2.000.00....

but turn out its comeout like this

[image]

and i already tried to use this reference and it's still wont work [Flutter - Wrap text on overflow, like insert ellipsis or fade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579918/flutter-wrap-text-on-overflow-like-insert-ellipsis-or-fade)
i want the text still gather with other without having space like `this was a long text` `loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong` <- this one

Comment: As price is probably important, maybe maniplulate the text to have K or M for thousand and million or something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextOverflow.ellipsis checks for a "\u2026" to clip the text. You can replace that with a "\u{200B}"

```
 child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 10,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 13.0),
                        child: Text(
                          ('\$ 900.000.000').replaceAll("", "\u{200B}"),
                          maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Colors.red,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Flexible(
                      flex: 3,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

[image: preview]

Comment: wow it work now. but where did you got the `/u{200B}`

Comment: That's a 0 width space unicode. It just needs a space to clip text. Followed this Git link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18761

Answer (score 0):

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 13.0),
                      child: const Text(
                        '\$ 900.000.000',
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                
                   Icon(
                      Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                    ),
                 
                ],
              ),
            ),
```