# How can I fix this "right Overflowed by 39 Pixels error" in the middle of a row?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I tried alining two rows within a SizedBox-widget and it doesn't look like that there should be an overflow right now, but there is one.

This is the code, and the picture of how it looks like right now is down below.

```
SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [

              //Profile
              Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    OutlinedButton(
                        onPressed: () => {Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const Profile()))
                        },
                        style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                            shape: const CircleBorder(),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2)
                        ),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: primary,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(profilePath),
                          radius: 24,
                        )
                    ),
                    //rowSpacer,
                    Text(profileName, style: categoryNF),
                  ],),
              ),

              // Likes
              Expanded(
              child: Row (
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () => {},
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.favorite_border,
                      size: 32,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                    ),
                  ),
                  //rowSpacer,
                  Text("$likes Likes", style: categoryNF),
                ],)
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrap your name `Text` with `Expanded` widget like this:

```
Expanded(child: Text(profileName, style: categoryNF),),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use this `Text(profileName,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, style: categoryNF)` for more refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579918/flutter-wrap-text-on-overflow-like-insert-ellipsis-or-fade)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but it sounds like you want to know how to fix the "right Overflowed by 39 Pixels" error in your code.

The easiest way to fix this is to simply add a padding to the right side of your row. For example:

```
Row(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0), // add this
  children: [
    // your widgets here
  ],
),
```

This will add 16 pixels of padding to the right side of your row, which should be enough to fix the overflow error.